# How to upload photo into UserProfile for specified user in django?

Tags: python, django, forms, upload

I have a *photo* field in my **UserProfile** model, so any user is able to upload his photo. I was thinking that all I need is *ModelForm* for the **UserProfile**, but without User specified it will fail, of course. But if I pass the **request.user** as a parameter into a form constructor - it won't work, too, because of the thing that form's UserProfile isn't connected with this user.

```
class ProfileUploadPhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('photo',)
```

Is there any way to set, which user's profile to modify?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it an instance of a `UserProfile` to update.

```
uploadform = ProfileUploadPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES,\
    instance=request.user.userprofile)

if uploadform.is_valid():
    uploadform.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, too, just silently fails. And photo is not uploaded.

Comment: Have you done anything to your ModelForm save method or validation?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I forgot to add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in form attributes.